# Twitter API request trends by Name (Search by name)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, twitter

**How I can do this process if that no API allows to request by specific name** 
*Any idea*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much luck there. Twitter API exposes two endpoints for searching trends:

1. [trends/locations](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/locations-with-trending-topics/overview) to get the available locations where there are trends
2. [trends/place](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place) to get the trending topics in said locations

> Returns the top 50 trending topics for a specific WOEID, if trending information is available for it.
>
> The response is an array of trend objects that encode the name of the trending topic, the query parameter that can be used to search for the topic on Twitter Search, and the Twitter Search URL.
>
> This information is cached for 5 minutes. Requesting more frequently than that will not return any more data, and will count against rate limit usage.
>
> The tweet_volume for the last 24 hours is also returned for many trends if this is available.

Check the return examples though:

```
"trends": [
      {
        "name": "#ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "promoted_content": null,
        "query": "%23ChainedToTheRhythm",
        "tweet_volume": 48857
      }
```

If you make a class like this:

```
public class Trend {
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string url {get; set;}
    // etc
}
```

And you [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) the array to a list `List<Trend>`, you can use in memory linq to search by name

```
    var trends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrendsResponse>(json);
    var newTrendList = trends.Where(t = t.name.Contains("targetName")).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for your time I have like this job to get trends every one hour, but I want to search on specific trend and the search process is currently performed

Comment: The only trend queried from the api, are those above. If you want to search for a specific trend in the list of trends, then the above is the only way I can think of.